# Easy question about $C_c^\infty(0,T)$ and $C_c^\infty((0,T);X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $f \in C_c^\infty(0,T).$ It follows that $f \in C^k(0,T)$ for all $k$, and so if $t_n \to t$ then
$$|f(t_n) - f(t)| + |f'(t_n) - f'(t)| + ... +|f^{(k)}(t_n) - f^{(k)}(t)| \to 0$$
for all $k$.

Now let $g \in C_c^\infty((0,T);X)$ where $X$ is a Banach space. Isn't it also the case then that 
$$\lVert g(t_n) - g(t) \rVert_{X} \to 0$$
if $t_n \to t$?

But I have heard people say that "there is no notion of convergence in these spaces because they are not properly normed spaces".

Comment: $g$ is a map which "eats" a function $f$ and gives you an element in $X$

Comment: @janmarqz: $g$ doesn't it anything. It's a generalization of $f$ that takes values in general Banach space $X$ rather than in $\bf R$. Otherwise it's the same.

Comment: could your please explain your definition of $C^{\infty}_c(0,T)$??

Comment: @janmarqz: it's standard definition for the space of smooth functions defined on the interval $(0, T)$.

Comment: then $f:(0,T)\to{\Bbb{R}}$, right?

Comment: @janmarqz Yes, $f:(0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ but $g:(0,T) \to X$

Comment: Perhaps the quoted statement refers to convergence in $C^\infty_c((0,T),X)$ and not $X$? As in, what would it mean for a sequence of functions $g_n : (0,T) \to X$ to converge to $g$ -- what is the norm on $C^\infty_c((0,T),X)$?

Comment: @fuglede Oh I see. Thanks, you should put that as answer.

Comment: Right, except right now I don't see why the uniform norm does not do the job.

Comment: maybe [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space] helps

Comment: @fuglede But it is true that $C_c^\infty((0,T);X) \subset C^k([0,T];X)$ right? Because of the compact support and all..

Comment: @janmarqz I don't think so, wiki does not have a lot about banach space-valued functions unfortunately.

Comment: @fuglede The uniform limit of a sequence of functions with compact support does in general not have compact support. Also, for $C_c^\infty$, one needs infinitely many derivatives to converge nicely, you can't capture that with a norm. For $C_c^\infty((0,T);X)$, you want a generalisation of the topology on the space of $\mathbb{R}$-valued test functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that
$$\lVert g(t_n) - g(t) \rVert_{X} \to 0$$
as $t_n\to t$, is simply a consequence of the continuity of $g: (0,T)\to X$ at $t$.